# Odoo module's menu root not showing

Tags: odoo

I just created a module and add a model and some menu items, But the menu item "Backup SQlite" is not showing on Odoo root menu, This is my code. Any Ideas why is this happening?

views.xml

```
<record id="utepda_backup_sqlite.backup_log_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Backup Log</field>
    <field name="res_model">utepda_backup_sqlite.backup</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    <field name="help" type="html">
        <p class="o_view_nocontent_smiling_face">No se han realizado backups</p>
    </field>
</record>

  <menuitem id="utepda_backup_sqlite.menu_root"
  name="Backup Sqlite" />

<!-- App menu items -->
  <menuitem id="menu_log"
  name="Backup log"
  parent="utepda_backup_sqlite.menu_root"
  sequence="10"
  action="utepda_backup_sqlite.backup_log_action" />
```

models.py

```
class BackupInfo(models.Model):
    _name = 'utepda_backup_sqlite.backup'
    _description = 'Clase que guarda la informacion de las salvas realizadas'

    name = fields.Char("Nombre")
    fecha_hora = fields.Datetime(string='Fecha-Hora')
```

ir.model.access.csv

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_backup_sqlite,access_backup_sqlite,model_utepda_backup_sqlite_backup,,1,1,1,1
```

Comment: Make sure `ir.model.access.csv` is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

It'll work if you have a menu root and a submenu root where your menu items will match on! Here is an example:

```
<!-- menu root -->
<menuitem id="sqlite_menu_root"
  name="Sqlite" />

<!-- submenu root -->
<menuitem id="sqlite_submenu_root"
  parent="sqlite_menu_root"
  name="Backup" />

<!-- App menu items -->
<menuitem id="sqlite_submenu_root"
  parent="sqlite_submenu_root"
  name="Backup Sqlite" 
  sequence="10"
  action="backup_sqlite_action"/>

<menuitem id="menu_log"
  name="Backup log"
  parent="utepda_backup_sqlite.menu_root"
  sequence="10"
  action="backup_log_action" />
```